# Merge [radeon] into [ati-radeon]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[radeon](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/radeon) (x13) should be merged into [ati-radeon](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ati-radeon) (x94). It should also be a synonym of the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.